# помогите с позицией элемента наклад на друг друга

Tags: css

Нам нужно создать два блока <div, каждый с двумя абзацами и разным цветом фона. Примените свойство абсолютного положения к первому элементу <div и свойство относительного положения ко второму элементу div. Расположите элементы так, чтобы они перекрывали друг друга. Сделайте так, чтобы первый элемент перекрывался вторым.
Я пробовал это сделать, но в моем случае второй элемент накладывается на первый, а не наоборот.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TASK-2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .header {
            position: absolute;
            width: 150px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .eve {
            position: relative;
            top: 40px; left: 40px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Laborum, debitis provident nemo?</div>
    <div class="eve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1336832/191482

Comment: Вам не надоело плодить аккаунты  и задавать один и тот же вопрос каждые 40 минут?

Comment: Тогда надо ему так и сказать и переоткрыть. А не плодить во первых аккаунты, во вторых вопросы

Comment: _«Сделайте так, чтобы первый элемент перекрывался вторым.»_ и _«в моем случае второй элемент накладывается на первый»_ - одно и то же, не? Зачем делать наоборот, если по заданию этого не требуется?

Answer (score -1):

Нужно было просто задать **z-index** обоим блокам =)

```css
.header{
position: absolute;
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: green;
z-index: 5;
}

.eve {
position: relative;
top: 40px; left: 40px;
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: yellow;
z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Laborum, debitis provident nemo?</div>
    <div class="eve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
```